# How do I wait for a Mouseclick in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, while-loop, wait

I am new to programming and created a code in Unity with c# which creates two lists with european countries and their capitals. then it should pick a random capital, say which one in the Debug.Log and the player can click on the corresponding countrie. The clicking and figuering out what was clicked works just fine, but after a random capital was picked by the programm I want the it to wait for a mousebutton press. I tried it with a while-loop, but the code I came up with just freezes when I press spacebar (without displaying the debug before the while-loop). I also tried using away/async and putting a delay after the if in the while loop but I don't understand anything about async and the delay did nothing. Glad for any help, my code is below.
I did not include void start() since it only fills the lists.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class Lists : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<string> laender = new List<string>();
    List<string> staedte = new List<string>();
    string clickedobj;
    string land;
    public int element = new int();
    int length = 37;
    int click = 1;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // fills the two lists
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            int element = (Random.Range(0, length));
            string land = laender[element];
            Debug.Log("int element: " + element);
            Debug.Log("Hauptstadt: " + staedte[element]);
            Debug.Log("Land: " + laender[element]);
            Debug.Log("string land: " + land); //random capital and according country is picked and displayed
            while(click == 1) // I also tried while(click == 1) but it didnt work
            {
                if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) //The while loop checks if the mousebutton is clicked
                {
                    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
                    click = 0; //if the meousebutton is clicked the program should exit the while-loop
                    string clickedobj = hit.collider.gameObject.name;
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Debug.Log("string land: " + land);
            //Debug.Log ("Target Position: " + clickedobj);
            if(clickedobj == laender[element])
            {
                Debug.Log("Richtig!");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("int element: " + element);
                Debug.Log("Falsch!, Richtig war: " + land + " Du hast auf " + clickedobj + " getippt.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Thread.Sleep` is the last thing you want to do in a frame based single threaded application ;)

`Update` is called once a frame. Even if you sleep within that frame it will not move to the next frame so no user input will be handled at all between your iterations. Rather simply check **once** per `Update` call!

Further you have a lot of fields but then hide these using local variables with the same name - most importantly  `element` and `clickedobj`! These class fields will never be assigned so when you later use them in outer scopes where your local variables are not available anymore you check the wrong values.

---

Now if I understand correctly there are two states in your app.

1. Idle -> waits for space click
2. Country selection -> waits for mouse click

so you could do

```
private enum State
{
    Idle,
    Selection
}

private State state;

private int element;

private void Update ()
{
    switch(state)
    {
        case State.Idle:
            // While in idle state you wait for the space press
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                // Make sure to assign the class fields not new local variables
                element = (Random.Range(0, length));
                land = laender[element];
                Debug.Log("int element: " + element);
                Debug.Log("Hauptstadt: " + staedte[element]);
                Debug.Log("Land: " + laender[element]);
                Debug.Log("string land: " + land);

                // Go to the selection state
                state = State.Selection;
            }
            break;

        case State.Selection:
            // While in selection mode you wait for a mouse click
            if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                var hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
                // Additionally check if you actually clicked on something
                if(hit.collider)
                {      
                    var clickedobj = hit.collider.name;
        
                    Debug.Log("string land: " + land);
        
                    if(clickedobj == laender[element])
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Richtig!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log("int element: " + element);
                        Debug.Log("Falsch!, Richtig war: " + land + " Du hast auf " + clickedobj + " getippt.");
                    }

                    // Go back to idle state
                    state = State.Idle;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

---

And then just a further tip: Instead of two independent lists rather have a proper class like

```
[Serializable]
public class Land
{
    public string Name;
    public string Capital;
}
```

and

```
public List<Land> lands = new List<Land>();
```

and fill this single list via Inspector or code.

and then later you have a single access for the random and comparison

```
element = Random.Range(0, lands.Count);
land = lands[element].Name;
Debug.Log("int element: " + element);
Debug.Log("Hauptstadt: " + lands[element].Capital);
Debug.Log("Land: " + lands[element].Name);
Debug.Log("string land: " + land);
```

this reduces index issue ;) It further would allow you to have a certain component on your clicked GameObjects and actually give it the according instance of the `Land` class and then not go by strings and names but actually check if the `Land` instance itself matches.